# display the multiple value in single field in drupal 7 view

Tags: views

[image]**display the related multiple value in single field to avoid duplication in drupal 7 view**

Guys help me to solve this issue.

### Now it's like this.

### **Name -----------------------------Organization**

### sam --------------------------------Ministry of public Health

### sam ---------------------------------It solution company

### **I want to display like below**

### **Name------------------------------Organization**

**sam----------------------------------Ministry of public Health, It solution company**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- open your view and select ur field which is filed collections
2- select the following settings [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by "Rewrite results" follow the following steps.

1) Edit the first field and exclude it from display.

2) Edit the second field and click on the "Rewrite results"

3) check "Rewrite the output of this field" checkbox.

4) find your fields in the "replacement Patterns" and put it in the textarea like this [field1],[field2]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replaying me but this is not 2 field. please check the above picture which I have uploaded

Comment: you get two records because you entered a separate node for each organization, so i suggest you to use https://www.drupal.org/project/textformatter this module to combine the organization by comma, and not to enter separate node for each organization.

Answer (score -1):

You can use views_php module. This module adds a field to your module that its content is php code. The rows and results of other fields are also available in the php code.

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, any PHP code that can be added via the CMS is a security issue.